# Gnokii SMS issue

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to setup a linux machine (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit) to send out SMS messages from a Nokia phone (Nokia E50) plugged in via USB through Gnokii.

I have downloaded/installed Gnokii, having edited the gnokiirc file (Posted below) I then try to run the command and send an SMS but get this error message:

```
user@server:~$ echo "gnokii test" | gnokii --sendsms 'mobile number entered here'

GNOKII Version 0.6.30

Couldn't read /home/groundwork/.config/gnokii/config config file
Couldn't read /etc/xdg/xdg-gnome-shell/gnokii/config config file
Gnokii serial_open: open: Permission denied
Couldn't open FBUS device: Permission denied
Gnokii serial_open: open: Permission denied
Couldn't open FBUS device: Permission denied
Gnokii serial_open: open: Permission denied
Couldn't open FBUS device: Permission denied
Telephone interface init failed: Command failed.

Quitting.
Command failed.
```

So obviously I know there are some permission errors there (not sure where I am supposed to change the permissions though). And I also tried to find the two files that couldn't be read, in order to edit them and/or change permissions, however they do not exist.

The command I ran to install gnokii was sudo apt-get install gnokii which completed with no errors.

Please see below the content of my gnokiirc file, which is in both the Home folder and is also located in the /etc location (as per gnokii's instructions).

```
# This is a sample ~/.gnokiirc file. Copy it into your
# home directory and name it .gnokiirc.
# See http://wiki.gnokii.org/index.php/Config for working examples.
#

[global]

# Set port to the physical port used to connect to your phone.
# Linux version is:
#port = /dev/ttyACM0
#
# For MacOSX you will need something like:
# port = /dev/cu.USA28X1P1.1
#
# For Win32 you want to use:
# port = com1:
# or similiar.
#
# FreeBSD (probably NetBSD and OpenBSD too) use:
# port = /dev/cuaa0
#
# With Linux-IrDA you will want to use
# port = /dev/ircomm0
# or similiar.
#
# Use this setting also for the Bluetooth connection:
# port = aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
# when using it with AT driver set it to:
#port = /dev/rfcomm0
# or similiar.
#
# For the Linux USB cables you will need one of the following settings (or
# similiar)
# port = /dev/ttyUSB0
#port = /dev/tts/USB0
# port = /dev/ttyACM0
# the last one will work only with AT driver. The correct setting should be
# given in the dmesg output.
#
# If you use connection type dku2libusb use it to denote which use endpoint
# you'd wish to use. It is useful when you have more than one phone connected
# to your computer using DKU2 cable. Numbering goes from 1 upwards.
# Default is 1.
# port = 1

# Set model to the model number of your phone. For the
# Symbian phones use:
# model = Nokia
# For other non-Nokia phones and when you want to use AT
# mode use:
model = AT
# If you can't figure out what to put here read the FAQ.
# If it still doesn't help, consult gnokii-ml or #gnokii at freenode.
#model = 2700
# There are few main models that should make use of the certain drivers.
# These are: 6110, 7110, 6510, 3110, 2110, 6160.

# Set IrDA device name.
# If you use irda connection you may want gnokii to autodetect the irda
# device it connects to. This is fine for most of the cases. if you have
# more than one device in range you may want to give manually the device
# name so gnokii correctly recognizes it. Use the name that you can see
# in the discovery log when the phone with infrared is in the range of
# your irda port.
# Note that you need to set this for each phone_ section separately. It
# isn't nested from the global section.
# irda_string = Nokia E50

# Initlength controls the number of characters sent to the
# phone during initialisation. You can either set it to
# the word "default" or a positive integer.
#
# You can try setting this value if you want to connect
# to the phone quicker. If you've never noticed the
# connection to be slow, it is suggested that you
# leave this alone. Read the initialisation code in fbus-xxxx
# to understand what this changes if you're curious.
initlength = default

# The type of the connection, for IR set this to infrared or irda.
# For the nk6110 driver only infrared is valid for the IrDA connection.
# See Docs/gnokii-ir-howto for more detailes on this.
# If you have 6210/6250/7110 phone and dau9p cable (the one you can
# use with 6100 series and cannot use hardware modem from the phone)
# you may want to use 'dau9p' value to get faster initialization.
# If you use dlr3 or dlr3p cable for nokia phones in FBUS mode (ie.
# you don't use model = AT) you may want to use 'dlr3p' value here.
# Note that it is recommended and currently the best way to use this
# cable with nk6510 driver.
#connection = dau9p
# With DKU-2 cable use the following setting if you want to libusb driver
# (recommended):
# connection = dku2libusb
# or the following setting if you want to use Linux kernel driver
# connection = dku2
# With DKU-5 cable use the following setting
# connection = dku5
# For Bluetooth and AT driver use the following setting
connection = serial
# For other Bluetooth settings use
# connection = bluetooth
# For infrared connection with phones other than Nokia 6110/6130/6150 use:
# connection = irda
# Don't forget to run: 'irattach irda0 -s' or similiar before running gnokii
# For connection with a PC/SC compatible Smart Card reader use:
# connection = pcsc

# Set this to 'yes' if you want gnokii to set and check the lock file in
# /var/lock directory. It avoids potential conflicts with other serial
# port software (eg. minicom). If you have wrong permissions for the
# directory, a warning will be generated. If you don't want a lockfile, set
# it to 'no'.
use_locking = no

# Baudrate to use on serial port connections.
# Currently used only by models AT and BIP/CIMD. Defaults to 19200.
serial_baudrate = 9600

# Force waiting after each send character the specified usec time.
# Value -1 forces the fastest 'block' writing,
# value 0 writes each character separately without any explicite waiting,
# other positive values specify the appropriate 1/1000000 sec delaying.
# Siemens M20 requires at least "1"! FIXME: Model-driven autodetection
#serial_write_usleep = -1

# Force serial port handshaking mode, useful primarily for "AT" model.
# Gnokii "AT" model uses software handshake by default.
# Possible values: hardware (RTS/CTS - 7 wires) or software (XON/XOFF - 3 wires)
#handshake = software

# If defined (not commented out by '#') it will quit Gnokii anytime
# when DCD line will drop.
#require_dcd = 0

# If you are using a bluetooth connection, you can specify the rfcomm
# channel number here. Default value is 1.
#rfcomm_channel = 1

# There may happen various timeouts during the communication with the phone.
# This parameter enables the retransmission policy. Ie. if the phone doesn't
# respond, we send the frame again. This happened mainly with the older
# phones. You may want to enable it when you see mysterious timeouts.
# Be very careful with this option. It is suspected to cause phone breakage
# with new DCT4 phones (like Nokia 6100). By default it is switched off
# (sm_retry = 0)
#sm_retry = 0

# Run the specified script(s) right after opening and initializing the device
# and before any communication (right before closing for disconnect_script).
# You may find handy to use it to connect your modem to SMS Center
# when using BIP or CIMD protocols
# Non-absolute path is relative to the specific directory where gnokii is run!
#connect_script = /absolute/path/to/gnokii/Docs/sample/cimd-connect
#disconnect_script =

# When sending SMS you can experience timeouts. This is the feature of the
# overloaded SMSCs. The phones waits for the response from the SMSC confirming
# that it received the short message. When the SMSC is DoSed with many requests
# it will take more time to get the response. Adjust it to your needs. The
# value is given in seconds to wait. Defaults to 10 seconds. Set to 0 to wait
# forever.
smsc_timeout = 10

# Set this to 1 if you want to break your phone with xgnokii. Works only
# with few Nokia models and FBUS communication
[xgnokii]
allow_breakage = 0

# Set bindir to point to the location of the various gnokiid binaries.
# In particular ensure that mgnokiidev is in this location, with
# permissions 4750, owned by root, group gnokii. Ensure you
# are in the gnokii group and that the group exists...
[gnokiid]
bindir = /usr/sbin/

# Any entries in the following two sections will be set as environment
# variables when running the scripts.
# Handy for use for $VAR substitutions in your chat(8) script.
[connect_script]
TELEPHONE = 12345678
[disconnect_script]


# The following parameters control how libgnokii handles the debugging messages.
# Currently there are three categories: "debug" controls the libgnokii
# normal debug output, "rlpdebug" controls the debug output of the RLP
# subsystem, and "xdebug" is used by the xgnokii or smsd.

[logging]

# where to log the debug output (on: stderr, off: /dev/null)
debug = off

# where to log the rlp debug output (on: stderr, off: /dev/null)
rlpdebug = off

# where to log X debug output (on: stderr, off: /dev/null)
xdebug = off
```

Please note this post is also here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2299068

Edit:
I have just had a brain wave and tried doing this:
Run command 'su root' and I get the following.

```
GNOKII Version 0.6.30

Couldn't read /home/groundwork/.config/gnokii/config config file
Couldn't read /etc/xdg/xdg-gnome-shell/gnokii/config config file         
Telephone interface init failed: Command timed out.
Quitting.
Command timed out.
```

Comment: Try running it with sudo.

Comment: Already tried that, exact same error message